# How does FLOAT map/relate to NUMBER in Oracle 10g?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

What is the FLOAT data type in Oracle 10g and how does it relate to NUMBER?

The only reference I can find to FLOAT in the Oracle documentation is in the BINARY_DOUBLE section of this page: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i140621 It seems to indicate that it stores a floating point number and allows you to specify bits of precision, but it doesn't reference the NUMBER type. The 11g docs don't mention FLOAT at all.

The book "Expert Oracle Database Architecture: Oracle Database 9i, 10g, and 11g Programming Techniques and Solutions, Second Edition" says:

> In addition to the NUMBER, BINARY_FLOAT, and BINARY_DOUBLE types, Oracle syntactically supports the following numeric datatypes:
>
> When I say "syntactically supports," I mean that a CREATE statement may use these datatypes, but under the covers they are all really the NUMBER type. ...
>
> - FLOAT(p): Maps to the NUMBER type.

What I don't understand is *how* it maps to NUMBER.

`NUMBER(p)` allows me to specify precision but the scale defaults to 0. It seems like `FLOAT(p)` is mapping to `NUMBER(decimal p, *)`, that is, fixed precision but variable scale, which is not something the NUMBER type allows as far as I can tell.

So, FLOAT is not just an alias but also provides behavior that NUMBER by itself does not offer?

Comment: I don't have an Oracle instance handy to check, but if I recall correctly FLOAT is defined in the package SYS.STANDARD as a subtype of NUMBER.  (In Oracle **most** numeric types are subtypes of NUMBER.  I believe that BINARY_FLOAT and BINARY_DOUBLE are one of the very few exceptions to this.  PLS_INTEGER might be another one but I'm not sure - check SYS.STANDARD).

Comment: @BobJarvis yes, it says `subtype FLOAT is NUMBER; -- NUMBER(126)`, but then again it also says `subtype BINARY_FLOAT is NUMBER;`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation in 10g is a bit unclear. It has improved quite a bit from 11.1 onwards:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#sthref94

In summary, `FLOAT` is the same as `NUMBER`, with two differences

1. `FLOAT` cannot specify the scale
2. In `FLOAT`, the precision is given in binary bits, in `NUMBER` in decimal digits, so `FLOAT(126)` means 126 bits of precision, `NUMBER(38)` means 38 decimal digits of precision

**EDIT**
Some examples show that a `FLOAT` is just a `NUMBER` in disguise.

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  n1 NUMBER(*,1),  f1 FLOAT(1), f2 FLOAT(2), f3 FLOAT(3),
  n2 NUMBER(*,2),  f4 FLOAT(4), f5 FLOAT(5), f6 FLOAT(6)
);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3);

SELECT n1, f1, f2, f3 FROM t;
  0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3

SELECT DUMP(n1), DUMP(f1), DUMP(f2), DUMP(f3) FROM t;
  Typ=2 Len=2: 192,31
  Typ=2 Len=2: 192,31
  Typ=2 Len=2: 192,31
  Typ=2 Len=2: 192,31

SELECT n2, f4, f5, f6 FROM t;
  0.33 0.33 0.33 0.33

SELECT DUMP(n2), DUMP(f4), DUMP(f5), DUMP(f6) FROM t;
  Typ=2 Len=2: 192,34
  Typ=2 Len=2: 192,34
  Typ=2 Len=2: 192,34
  Typ=2 Len=2: 192,34
```

Be careful, though, the conversion factor from Float's precision bits to Number's decimal digits is not 3, but around 3.32. To be exact *digits* = ceil(*bits* / log(2,10).

Comment: Thanks, that page is much better. So, just to make sure, `FLOAT(p)` has no direct equivalent using `NUMBER`? It seems like there's a lot of bad information on the oracle forums and internet in general where people are confusing number, float, binary_float, and "floating-point numbers" with each other.

Comment: Then what is the scale for float?

Comment: @JavaTechnical "Scale cannot be specified, but is interpreted from the data" (Oracle documentation, see link above)

Comment: @wolφi That means the scale can be any, but the total digits must be 126. Am i right?

Comment: @JavaTechnical No, you can't specify the scale at all. And no, the number of *bits*, not digits, must be between 1 and 126. I'll edit the answer and add some examples.